# wrapfigure not adding space below figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, graphics, wrapfigure

A standalone extract from my paper:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz, wrapfig, array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Answer}
% wrapfiure start
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4.4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2, 0) -- (2, 0) (1, 0) -- (1, 2) coordinate (a) (-1, 0) -- (-1, 3) coordinate (b);
\draw[fill=black] (1, 2) circle (2pt) (-1, 3) circle (2pt);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=5pt, raise=5pt}] (1, 0) -- (a) node[midway, xshift=.8cm] {\footnotesize 100 m};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt, raise=5pt}] (-1, 0) -- (b) node[midway, xshift=-.8cm] {\footnotesize 150 m};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
% wrapfiure end
\begin{align*}
    \text{Initial difference in heights} & = 150\ \mathrm{m} - 100\ \mathrm{m} \\
    & = 50\ \mathrm{m}
\end{align*}
Distance travelled by the body in 2 seconds:
\begin{align*}
    h_1 & = ut + \frac{1}{2}gt^2 \\
    & = 0 + \frac{1}{2}g(2)^2 \\
    h_1 & = 2g
\end{align*}
After 2 seconds, height at which the first body will be $H_1 = 150 - 2g$.\\
Similarly, $h_2 = 2g$ and $H_2 = 100 - 2g$\\\\
\begin{tabular}{ll}
     & After 2 seconds, difference in height \\
    = & $H_1 - H_2$ \\
    = & (150 - 2g) - (100 - 2g) \\
    = & 150 - 2g - 100 + 2g \\
    = & 50
\end{tabular}\\\\
This difference in heights doesn't vary with time.

\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image: Compiled code result]

Seems like `wrapfigure` hasn't done its work. How to make it do it?

Comment: Wrapfig assumes the lines are precisely spaced `\baselineskip` apart.  Any extra vertical spacing (such as around equations) will throw off its calculation.   The number of lines argument (optional) can be used in this case, although it may take a few tries to find the right number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with the `\InsertBoxL` command from the plain TeX macro package `insbox`; and a slightly different code. In addition, I replaced the fractionary coefficients in display style with the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath`, which look better, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz, wrapfig, array, calc}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Answer}
\InsertBoxL{0}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2, 0) -- (2, 0);
\draw (1, 0) -- (1, 2) coordinate (a);
\draw (-1, 0) -- (-1, 3) coordinate (b);
\draw[fill=black] (1, 2) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (-1, 3) circle (2pt);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=5pt, raise=5pt}] (1, 0) -- (a) node[midway, xshift=.8cm] {\footnotesize 100 m};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt, raise=5pt}] (-1, 0) -- (b) node[midway, xshift=-.8cm] {\footnotesize 150 m};
\end{tikzpicture}}[-4]
\noindent Initial difference in heights
$ \begin{aligned}[t]
    & = 150\,\mathrm{m} - 100\,\mathrm{m} \\
    & = 50\,\mathrm{m}
\end{aligned} $ \medskip\\
Distance travelled by the body in 2 seconds:

\begin{align*}
    h_1 & = ut + \mfrac{1}{2}gt^2 \\
    & = 0 + \mfrac{1}{2}g(2)^2 \\
    h_1 & = 2g
\end{align*}
After 2 seconds, height at which the first body will be $H_1 = 150 - 2g$.\\
Similarly, $h_2 = 2g$ and $H_2 = 100 - 2g$\\\\
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-4pt}
\begin{tabular}{L{\widthof{=}}l}
     & After 2 seconds, difference in height \\
    = & $H_1 - H_2$ \\
    = & (150 - 2g) - (100 - 2g) \\
    = & 150 - 2g - 100 + 2g \\
    = & 50
\end{tabular}\\\\
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
This difference in heights doesn't vary with time.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `wrapfigure` can be used perfectly fine. The problem is you're crunching a lot in one paragraph, and using two `align`'s within one paragraph can cause problems in some scenario's. Instead, create paragraphs by using blank lines:

```
\section{Answer}
% wrapfiure start
\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{l}{4.7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2, 0) -- (2, 0) (1, 0) -- (1, 2) coordinate (a) (-1, 0) -- (-1, 3) coordinate (b);
\draw[fill=black] (1, 2) circle (2pt) (-1, 3) circle (2pt);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=5pt, raise=5pt}] (1, 0) -- (a) node[midway, xshift=.8cm] {\footnotesize 100 m};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt, raise=5pt}] (-1, 0) -- (b) node[midway, xshift=-.8cm] {\footnotesize 150 m};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
% wrapfiure end

\leavevmode
\begin{align*}
    \text{Initial difference in heights} & = 150\ \mathrm{m} - 100\ \mathrm{m} \\
    & = 50\ \mathrm{m}
\end{align*}

Distance travelled by the body in 2 seconds:
\begin{align*}
    h_1 & = ut + \frac{1}{2}gt^2 \\
    & = 0 + \frac{1}{2}g(2)^2 \\
    h_1 & = 2g
\end{align*}

After 2 seconds, height at which the first body will be $H_1 = 150 - 2g$.
Similarly, $h_2 = 2g$ and $H_2 = 100 - 2g$.

\begin{tabular}{ll}
     & After 2 seconds, difference in height \\
    = & $H_1 - H_2$ \\
    = & (150 - 2g) - (100 - 2g) \\
    = & 150 - 2g - 100 + 2g \\
    = & 50
\end{tabular}
This difference in heights doesn't vary with time.
```

You should always try to avoid a forced line break for normal text. If you're resorting to this because you don't like the automatic indentation, add `\usepackage{parskip}`. Instead of indentation for new paragraphs, this will give spacing between paragraphs.

Additionally, `wrapfigure` sometimes makes a wrong guess about your figure height. You can see the `[7]` defines the height of your figure in amount of 'lines', which is distorted a bit by the use of mathematics.

Also, the `\leavevmode` is necessary because an `align` should always be preceded by text. The insertion of `\leavevmode` is as if you had inserted text without any height. You still see however that there is some white space before the equation. Again, you should always precede equations with text.

The idea of wrapfigure as opposed to the other answer is that you can use `\caption` and such. That won't work over there.